# Picking random positive integers $ai$ , what is the $P(\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=m)$?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

"Picking random positive intergers $a_i$" means that $a_i\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}^+$, all $a_i$ are selected uniformly from $\{1,2,3,\cdots,N,\cdots\}$.

Or, I want to know $\lim\limits_{N\rightarrow +\infty} P(\gcd(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=m), a_i\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_N(1\le i \le n)$.

For the sake of convenience, we let $b_n=\gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$.

We know $P(b_2=m)=\dfrac{1}{m^2\zeta(2)}$.
However, for the subsequent probabilities, I am unable to calculate them correctly.

**my answer**

$P(b_3=m)=P(m|b_2)P(m|a_3)P(gcd(\frac{b_2}{m},\frac{a_3}{m})=1)$

$P(m|b_2)=\sum\limits_{m|n}P(b_2=n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}P(b_2=km)=\frac{1}{m^2}\zeta(2)$,

$P(m|a_3)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}P(a_3=km)=\frac{1}{m}$

If $P(gcd(\frac{b_2}{m},\frac{a_3}{m})=1)=\frac{1}{\zeta(2)},P(b_3=m)=(\frac{\zeta(2)}{m^2})\cdot\frac{1}{m}\cdot \zeta(2)=\frac{\zeta^2(2)}{m^3}$,

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}P(b_3=i)=\zeta(3)\zeta^2(2)$

But it is clear that the correct result is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}P(b_3=i)=1$.
I want to know what is the probability $P(b_i=m)(i>2)$.

Comment: There is no such thing as "random positive integers", not until you posit a distribution function (and don't say, "uniformly distributed", because there's no such thing as a uniform distribution on the integers). You're probably talking about a limit as $r\to\infty$ with $n$ integers selected uniformly at random from $1,2,\dotsc,r$, but if that's what you mean, then that's what you should write.

Comment: $P(b_n=m)<P($each $a_i$ is a multiple of $m)\approx(\frac1m)^n.$

Comment: @Karl Yes, you are right. Initally, I want to know how fast ${b_n}$ converges to 1. Apparently, $b_{n+1}=1$ when $b_n=1$ and $P(b_{n+1}=1)>0$ when $b_n>1$.

Comment: As $n$ increases, the $P(b_n=1) $incresaes.  Although $P(b_2=1) =\frac{6}{\pi^2}> 0.6 , P(b_{n+1}=1)>P(b_n=1)>0.6$，I still want to know the convergence speed of the $\{b_n\}$.